# Defining location on X axis for a parametric 3D model

Tags: python, scripting

Building a parametric 3D shoe sole and can't find a way to set the location for the start of the toe spring.
Despite scripting a start of the spring at **10%** of the surface length, the spring starts in the middle of the surface somehow.
Some script snippets of interest:

```
# Define params for different areas
sole_length = 24 / 100  # Length in meters (converted from cm)
toe_spring_angle_rad = -8 * (math.pi / 180)  # Convert degrees to radians
toes_perc = 0.16
forefoot_perc = 0.39
midfoot_perc = 0.3
heel_perc = 0.15
```

```js
def calculate_z(x):
    # Define the start of the spring at 10% of the sole length from the front
    spring_start_x = sole_length * 0.1  

    # Calculate the relative position for `x` beyond the spring start
    if x <= (sole_length - spring_start_x):
        # Calculate the reverse progression from back to front starting from the spring start
        progression = ((sole_length - spring_start_x) - x) / (sole_length - spring_start_x)
        
        # Ensure the elevation increases towards the front
        z = math.tan(toe_spring_angle_rad) * (1 - progression) * (sole_length - spring_start_x)
        return z
    else:
        # Return 0 for the initial 10% of the sole length to keep it flat
        return 0
```

[image]

Looks like that the function takes the X-Y crossing as the reference for calculating the start of the Spring which may be why it starts in the middle of the sole surface. Any idea what's happening and how to make sure the spring_start variable is understood to be at 10% off of the tip of the toe area? Thanks all.

Comment: Based on your example I'm not sure if you want to start from min x or max x. You can get either from `context.object.bound_box` as your starting reference `min_x = min([b[0] for b in bbox])` then offset that value by your "spring_start_x ".

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am getting there, slowly...